# MATLAB error while convert str2num

Tags: matlab, runtime-error

i'm completely new to matlab and this is my first question.
I found a program like this

```
x = inputdlg('foo');
x = str2num(x{1})
```

and trying to make some gui from it, put this line to callback function of push button:

```
x=get(handles.edit1, 'String')
x=str2num(x{1})
```

and it works, but not after i add this the same thing with different variable

```
y=get(handles.edit2, 'String')
y=str2num(y{1})
```

command window said

```
Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Error in regresilinear>pushbutton1_Callback (line 128)
x=str2num(x{1})

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in regresilinear (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
@(hObject,eventdata)regresilinear('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

I found out that the output from command window is different when it's running and not with the same input.
When it got errors:

```
x =

0 1 2 3
```

when not (the first time)

```
x = 

    '0 1 2 3'
```

It doesn't give any error if i delete the str2num line.
I hope somebody can help fix the problem.

Comment: i found out that error happens when i change the String properties of edit1 from 'Edit Text' to ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a clear workspace and

```
x=get(handles.edit1, 'String');
x=str2num(x);
```

or better:

```
x=str2num(get(handles.edit1, 'String'));
```

`{}` are used for accessing the elements of a cell array. You are probably trying to use it on a string and that is why you are getting that error.

Comment: Thanks HebeleHododo, i followed your instructions and did it. Still don't know what was the problem

Comment: @VictorioPui So, did it work? If it did, it was probably because `x` was defined as a cell array in your workspace.

Comment: yes it is now, after started new workspace and use the same code.
I found out that editing the edit1 String properties results the error for str2num conversion